# svnadmin dump outputs a partial backup

Tags: dump, svn

I'm trying to dump my SVN repository in a scheduled task.
The problem is that when it's running in the scheduled task its only outputting a part of the repository (about 476MB instead of about 2G).

Scheduled task is in a bash file, script is:

```
svnadmin dump /home/it/svn/source > /home/it/IT_backup/backups/source.dump
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know the issue...since I ran into the same exact thing.

See here: [Subversion backup dump - just need something very simple](https://serverfault.com/questions/417487/subversion-backup-dump-just-need-something-very-simple)

Here's what I found to fix it:

You have to redirect output such as svndump.sh > /var/log/svndump.log 2>&1

This will cause the script to finish correctly.  I forget why to be honest...but it works.

Comment: I wish I could find the page I found the answer on...so far no luck and I'm not a Linux admin.  If I find it I'll post back here.